# can a custom domain be pointed a specific google app engine version domain?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-apps

an App Engine app can be deployed with a specific version ID
  http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html

such that if the original app has this default domain:
  myapp.appspot.com

and you can point your own custom domain to this using Google Apps
  www.myapp.com -->  (CNAME) myapp.appspot.com

BUT you can also upload a version identifier with your app and access it like this:
  newversion.myapp.appspot.com

What I am wondering is if it is possible to hook up a custom domain to this non-default version of the app?
  v2.myapp.com --> newversion.myapp.appspot.com  ??

I dont think this is supported... but was hoping someone could verify (because I can't find any hard documentation saying "no you cant do this")

---

EDIT: if you're stumbling upon this... you can use the [dispatch.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/dispatchref) file to point to specific SERVICE but not VERSION... so there is still no "built-in" solution for this as of the end of 2017

Answer (score 3):

This has just become available: GAE version 1.6.3 will include feature to map custom domain to a specific version of an app.

https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/google-appengine/detHVsR2Y5I/discussion

Comment: How to configure this?

Comment: As per docs: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/ You need to configure the wildcard domain mapping.

Comment: @Peter Knego That link is redirecting to another page. Could you please elaborate your answer?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps not the final official word, but there is an accepted bug report on Google App Engine (GAE) which seems to be related to your question. If I understood your question (and the bug report) correctly, the answer would be that it's not currently possible to point a sub-domain to a specific custom version of your app on GAE.

See the bug report here:

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2878

The bug is in the context of Facebook Connect and testing, but comments seem to indicate a wider issue with the inability for GAE to have a custom domain point to a specified version of one's app.

See also the Google Groups thread (linked from the bug report) here:

http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/3e85fc4ae426a46f

Answer (score 2):

I just gave this a try and I now have the following setup:

- `CNAME` record: `*.example.com. -> ghs.google.com.`
- Mapped `*.example.com` in Google Apps to my App Engine application

Now when I go to http://versionA.example.com/ it serves up versionA (previously this was found at http://versionA.myappid.appspot.com/).

Apparently you can do fancier things like http://versionA.appengine.example.com by using `*.appengine.example.com` instead of `*.example.com`.

See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain and scroll down to "More About Wildcard Subdomain Mapping"

Comment: i'm hoping this is what's up. some appengine answers do have 5 year shelf life.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24281343/451710) worked for me:

Add a CNAME entry in your DNS configuration with ALIAS `v2` and HOST `ghs.googlehosted.com`

Modify the dispatch file:

```
dispatch:

    - url: "v2.myapp.com/*"
      module: webmodule
```

More info here:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/routing

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not. I tried to do this recently and after banging my head against it came to the conclusion that you can not do this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like this feature, too. But it's not possible right now.
I'd be a nice feature for beta testing.
Right now, I deploy each version two times, first as beta version for beta testing and second as version number (for example 12020a) for default version switching.